# Check if user can open a file type in a web site

Tags: javascript, filesystems

I'm building a site where the user can download ePub files and Adobe Digital Edition files. Is it possible for a browser to know if the system can open a specific type of file or file with a specific extension before the file is actually downloaded?

I have some vague memory that I read about how WebKit could do this, but I can't find any useful info when searching.

Would I like to do is show a warning message if the user cant open the file he/she is about to download/buy.

// Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, browser doesn't have access for such OS resources

PS: "cannot open" is a bit vague definition. User could have the necessary software installed, but don't have the extension registered - does it count as "cannot open"?